# OpenGL 3.2 Core Profile Guide

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

Can anyone suggest a guide for learning the OpenGL 3.2 core profile?

The SDK is hard to read, and most of the guides I have seen only taught the old method.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't know any good guide but I can make you a quick summary

I'll assume that you are already familiar with the basics of shaders, vertex buffers, etc. If you don't, I suggest you read a guide about shaders first instead, because all OpenGL 3 is based on the usage of shaders

On initialisation:

- Create and fill vertex buffers using `glGenBuffers`, `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID)` and `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW)`
- Same for index buffers, except that you use `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` instead of `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`
- Create textures exactly like you did in previous versions of OpenGL (`glGenTextures`, `glBindTexture`, `glTexImage2D`)
- Create shaders using `glCreateShader`, set their GLSL source code using `glShaderSource`, and compile them with `glCompileShader` ; you can check if it succeeded with `glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &out)` and retrieve error messages using `glGetShaderInfoLog`
- Create programs (ie. a group of shaders bound together, usually one vertex shader and one fragment shader) with `glCreateProgram`, then bind the shaders you want using `glAttachShader`, then *link* the program using `glLinkProgram` ; just like shaders you can check linking success with `glGetProgram` and `glGetProgramInfoLog`

When you want to draw:

- Bind the vertex and index buffers using `glBindBuffer` with arguments `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` and `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` respectively
- *Bind* the program with `glUseProgram`
- Now for each varying variable in your shaders, you have to call `glVertexAttribPointer` whose syntax is similar to the legacy `glVertexPointer`, `glColorPointer`, etc. functions, except for its first parameter which is an identifier for the varying ; this identifier can be retrieved by calling `glGetAttribLocation` on a linked program
- For each uniform variable in your shaders, you have to call `glUniform` ; its first parameter is the location (also a kind of identifier) of the uniform variable, which you can retrieve by calling `glGetUniformLocation` (warning: if you have an array named "a", you have to call the function with "a[0]")
- For each texture that you want to bind, you have to call `glActiveTexture` with `GL_TEXTUREi` (i being different for each texture), then `glBindTexture` and then set the value of the uniform to i
- Call `glDrawElements`

This is the basic things you have to do. Of course there are other stuff, like vertex array objects, uniform buffers, etc. but they are merely for optimization purposes

Other domains like culling, blending, viewports, etc. remained mostly the same as in older versions of OpenGL

I also suggest you study [this demo program](http://www.dhpoware.com/demos/gl3HelloWorld.html) (which uses vertex array objects). The most interesting file is main.cpp

Hope this can help

Comment: One of the better modern OpenGL (core 3.2+) "short summaries" I've seen in a while. Will probably make even more sense when coming from 1.x/2.x and trying to get up-to-date through newer tutorials. Good as a mindmap.

Comment: One thing that tripped me was that you have to use VAO and VBO to draw. Otherwise you'll get GL_INVALID_OPERATION when calling glVertexAttribPointer. At least that was the case on Mac OS X.